# How to update the topology of a geometry efficiently in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, typed-arrays

I want to avoid creating new typed arrays and the consequent gc().
I made my geometry using BufferedGeometry. Upon receiving events, my vertex and the `faces` indices are updated. I can update the coordinates by setting `verticesNeedUpdate` but it does not update the faces. The update is called ~20-50 times per second, which can be heavy on the browser. How can I do this by avoiding creating heavy garbage for the JavaScript Garbage Collector? (See method `update()` below).

```
function WGeometry77(verts, faces) {
    THREE.Geometry.call( this );
    this.type = 'WGeometry77';
    this.parameters = {};
    // Initially create the mesh the easy way, by copying from a BufferGeometry
    this.fromBufferGeometry( new MyBufferGeometry77( verts, faces ) ); 
};

WGeometry77.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Geometry.prototype );
WGeometry77.prototype.constructor = WGeometry77;

WGeometry77.prototype.update = function(verts, faces) {
    var geom = this;
    var nl = Math.min(geom.vertices.length, verts.length/3);
    for ( var vi = 0; vi < nl; vi ++ ) {
        geom.vertices[ vi ].x = verts[vi*3+0];
        geom.vertices[ vi ].y = verts[vi*3+1];
        geom.vertices[ vi ].z = verts[vi*3+2];
    }
    var nf = Math.min(geom.faces.length, faces.length/3);
    for ( var fi = 0; fi < nf; fi ++ ) {
        geom.faces[ fi ].a = faces[fi*3+0];
        geom.faces[ fi ].b = faces[fi*3+1];
        geom.faces[ fi ].c = faces[fi*3+2];
    }
    geom.verticesNeedUpdate = true;  // Does not update the geom.faces
}
```

PS. My code is written in Emscripten, which does something like this:

```
var verts = Module.HEAPF32.subarray(verts_address/_FLOAT_SIZE, verts_address/_FLOAT_SIZE + 3*nverts);
```

What I want to do is almost *animating*, or a *dynamic* geometry (calculated using Marching Cubes). But my topology (the graph of the mesh) is also updated. Which ThreeJS class I should use? If there exists no such class, should I create we create a new class like `UpdatableBufferedGeometry`?

Comment: Update the `BufferGeometry` directly. Do not instantiate a `Geometry` for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you. Would you see my comment below @MrDoob's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update `THREE.BufferGeometry` after it has rendered, you can use this pattern:

```
geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ( index, x, y, z );

geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

For indexed `BufferGeometry`, you can change the `index` array like so:

```
geometry.index.array[ index ] = value;

geometry.index.needsUpdate = true;
```

You cannot resize buffers -- only change their contents. You can pre-allocate larger arrays and use

```
geometry.setDrawRange( 0, numVertices );
```

three.js r.78

Comment: If I "cannot change the index array if you are using indexed BufferGeometry", then what is the solution? ( @mrdoob ) . A new class in ThreeJS for this purpose? I can do a pull request for it.

Comment: Sorry. Corrected answer.

Comment: Perfect ! I exactly needed using `setDrawRange()`, so that I can reuse the same object using a different number of triangles. In my test, it seems it does not even need setting the `needsUpdate` (both). r77

Comment: I got a question: after a partial update,as in your example,will the whole buffer be uploaded to the GPU,or just the updated range?

Comment: All of it, but you can do a partial update by setting `attribute.setDynamic( true )` and setting `attribute.updateRange`. See, for example, https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_simple_gi.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you want efficiency, you should create a `BufferGeometry` instead of a `Geometry`.

You can use the source code of this example as reference:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_uint

Comment: I have a BufferGeometry. When I update it directly (see below), the changes are not reflected on screen. Only when I make a Geometry from it. When the Mesh is added, if I do the following I don't see any visual change in my mesh in the next renderer.render(). I do this:

        `reused_geometry.attributes.position[4] += 20;`
        `reused_geometry.index.array[2] = 9;`

Even if I remove the mesh and created another mesh from the same geometry object instance, it doesn't update on screen.  My intention is to avoid even instantiating the BufferGeometry in my animation loop. @WestLangley

Comment: I derived a class from BufferGeometry called `MyBufferGeometry77` (See main code). Maybe I am doing it wrong, e.g. I should implement a virtual method?